# unique_ptr can't initialize

Tags: c++, initialization, unique-ptr, member-initialization

I have the following code in a project, and it gives me an error C2059, syntax error "new" that the `unique_ptr` line is wrong.

```
#include <memory>

class Nothing {
public:
    Nothing() { };
};
class IWriter
{
    public:
        IWriter() {
        }

        ~IWriter() {
        }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Nothing> test(new Nothing());
};
```

What is happening here?

Comment: I tested both `test(new Nothing);` and `test(new Nothing());`

Comment: You need to initialise it in the constructor, not in the definition.

Comment: @David That is possible as of C++11.

Comment: Next time, please include the error message.

Comment: I did, ERROR C2059, Syntax Error: new

Comment: @SinisterMJ As someone who does not use MSVC, I have no idea what  ERROR C2059 means. And *"Syntax Error: new"* is not an error message.

Comment: Actually it is the precise message: `Error 1 error C2059: syntax error : 'new' d:\tfs\development\IWriter.h`

Comment: @SinisterMJ If that is true, this is dumb even by MSVC standards.

Comment: Yeah, guess why I had no idea what was wrong with my code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use [default member initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization), but in the wrong way. It must be simply a **brace initializer** (or equals initializer) (included in the member declaration).

You could use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11):

```
std::unique_ptr<Nothing> test{ new Nothing() };
```

Or [member initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class IWriter
{
    public:
        IWriter() : test(new Nothing) {
        }
        ~IWriter() {
        }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Nothing> test;
};
```

Comment: List initialization only works for C++11+

Comment: `unique_ptr` is a part of C++11 and onwards, and C++11 is 5 years old. How long do we need to keep writing "C++11 onwards"?

Comment: Interestingly enough, the list initialization did not work (VS2013), the init in the construction works